# How do I get C:/ on my command line

Tags: command-line

I am on Windows 10.

What I am trying to do is load Adobe Dreamweaver extensions via the command line on Windows.  I want to navigate to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Extension Manager CSx\

I am following the instructions [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/extension-manager/using/command-line-extension-manager-cs6.html).

If I choose Command Prompt (Admin) I get `C:\Windows\system32>`

If I choose Command Prompt only I get `C:\Users\USER>`

How do I get to  `C:\`

This is what is happening.  [See screen recording](https://youtu.be/YujWjfKH1C4)

Comment: You're already on C:\ - the `>` just tells you you're at the prompt for that drive.

Comment: you can't get `C:/` because `/` is not a path separator on Windows

Comment: actually, the path seperator is U+005C, which on most english-language systems should be \ but depending on the localization and code sheet can show as various characters (including /, though rather uncommon).

Comment: \ is the official path separator for Windows, but I've found that both will work in both `cmd` and PowerShell

Comment: @Alex it depends. Most GUI apps will accept both types of slashes, but most command line apps don't

Comment: @Ruscal I only see Japanese and Korean Windows map the path separator to `¥` and `₩`. I've never seen it on any other locales

Comment: In your video you change your directory to the root directory of your system drive. Your question makes no sense, you already know how to navigate to the root directory, per your own video you recorded

Comment: I am successfully navigating to the root directory because Ken White explained how to do that as in 'cd ..'  Now, as you can see in video, I get an error message when I try to execute my request to go to the Extension Manager Folder.  Can you see what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: So you significantly changed your question. After it was answered by Ken?  I am tempted to restore the original revision but add some details from the current revision because as-is the question is confusing because you ask how to do something and do said thing in your example.

Comment: I think its weird that this question is closed. Apart from that the description might be not clear enough, the question is more than valid. I always have that when I open my command prompt that I am in the Z drive. Thus, I would like to know how to enter the C drive, thus why I looked at this question. I find some programmers often to be too strict on this site, cut the guy some slack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typing `cd \` will move you from any folder on the drive to the root folder of that drive.

If you're in `C:\Windows\System32`, type `cd \` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to `C:\`.

If the path has spaces, enclose it in double-quotes. So, in your case, from `C:\Users\YourName`, type `cd "\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Extension Manager CSx\"` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Other useful options:

Typing `cd ..` will move you up  one level from the current directory (for instance, from `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows`

Typing `cd \newfolder` will move you to a new folder relative to the drive root (for example, from `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Users\YourName`, type `cd \Users\YourName`).

Typing `cd /d d:\temp` will change drives and directories in one operation (for instance, from `C:\Users` to `D:\temp`)

Type `cd /?` at the command prompt for more options.

Comment: `cd /?` gave what information I was searching, thanks!

Comment: If you are in Z drive and you would like to get to the C drive, type: C:

Answer (score 1):

`cd "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Extension Manager CSx\"`

`cd` stands for Change Directory. It changes the directory you're currently looking at to the one you specified

You can do `cd C:\` to change to C

Answer (score -3):

You want to use the PROMPT command, most likely you are looking for `prompt $P` where the normal prompt in Windows is `prompt $P$G`

```
C:\> help prompt

Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.

PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special
codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)   
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)   
  $D   Current date   
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)   
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)   
  $G   > (greater-than sign)   
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)   
  $L   < (less-than sign)   
  $N   Current drive  
  $P   Current drive and path   
  $Q   = (equal sign)   
  $S     (space)  
  $T   Current time   
  $V   Windows version number   
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed   
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports the
following additional formatting characters:

  $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

  $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
       drive.
```